# Setting up public plumber API?

Tags: rstudio-server, plumber

I'm trying to set up a plumber API (0.4.6) on rstudio-server running on AWS Linux, so that our external analytics system can make requests to R. I've got firewall ports open on 8787 (for Rstudio, which is working fine) and on 5762 (for the API, which isn't working). If I kick off a swagger API from within Rstudio, that works fine locally. If I remap the rstudio interface to 5762, that works fine (so not apparently a firewall problem). But we simply cannot find a way to expose a plumber API on 5762.

Suggestions gratefully received…

Answer (score 0):

what IP are you using?

Plumber respond by default on 127.0.0.1

There are probaly rules in places to prevent you from connecting to localhost from an external host.

Try 0.0.0.0

```
pr$run(host="0.0.0.0")
```